# Ubuntu 20.04 Is Constantly Freezing

Tags: gnome, freeze

I recently switched to Ubuntu and I'm having problems with my computer's performance. The system freezes (I can't move the mouse either) while running extremely basic tasks, such as browsing and using a code editor.
After running a hardware check, I noticed that my old HDD was corrupted and damaged.

Thinking that this was the source of the freezes, I bought a new SSD and replaced my laptop's hard drive. The OS boots up almost immediately and I am satisfied with its speed.

However, the freezes continued to occur. I ran a memtest and everything seemed to be fine...
Is there anybody that has experienced a similar problem?

I'm tired of troubleshooting my computer as it has negatively influenced my productivity over the last months.

Here are the log files:

```
15:01:29 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
14:52:28 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
14:51:40 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
14:47:57 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
14:47:45 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
14:45:25 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
14:43:52 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
14:42:54 systemd: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
14:42:45 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
14:42:43 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
14:42:42 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=878] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
14:42:42 nautilus: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
14:42:42 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=878] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
14:42:42 NetworkManager: <info>  [1619005362.0201] agent-manager: agent[cb6596f52dd5ed9f,:1.40/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
14:42:41 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
14:42:24 systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
14:42:24 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
14:42:24 systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
14:42:24 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.40' (uid=1000 pid=1294 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
14:39:41 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
14:35:34 avahi-daemon: Registering new address record for 2a02:587:350f:903a:df99:3302:6ded:38c5 on wlp2s0.*.
14:32:46 anacron: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
14:32:46 systemd: anacron.service: Succeeded.
14:31:22 whoopsie: [14:31:22] online
14:31:21 NetworkManager: <info>  [1619004681.1227] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
14:31:20 whoopsie: [14:31:20] offline
14:31:20 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
14:31:20 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
14:31:20 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
14:31:20 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=654 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
14:31:20 NetworkManager: <info>  [1619004680.6528] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
14:31:11 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
14:30:02 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
14:27:32 wpa_supplicant: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-71 noise=9999 txrate=72200
14:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
14:16:10 wpa_supplicant: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-48 noise=9999 txrate=72200
13:54:45 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
13:54:43 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
13:54:40 firefox: [GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1002/0x9874
13:54:39 systemd: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
13:54:29 gnome-shell: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
13:54:28 systemd: gnome-launched-firefox.desktop-4615.scope: Succeeded.
13:53:43 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
13:53:35 firefox: [GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1002/0x9874
13:53:35 systemd: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
13:52:59 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
13:52:57 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=878] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ChromeGnomeShell'
13:52:55 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
13:52:54 firefox: [GFX1-]: PCI candidate 0x1002/0x9874
13:52:53 systemd: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
13:52:49 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

System Info:
Memory: 5.5GBs
Processor: AMD A12-9720p radeon r7, 12computecores 4c+8g x 4
Graphics: AMD Radeon (tm) r7 m340 / AMD Radeon r7 graphics
Disk Capacity: 250GBs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123279/discussion-on-question-by-pioyi-ubuntu-20-04-is-constantly-freezing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 6G RAM, a 2G /swapfile is too small.

**Note**: You may need to add more RAM.

In `terminal` do `sysctl vm.swappiness` and it should return 60 (we may change this value later).

**SWAP**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 6G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

*"I ran a memtest and everything seemed to be fine"*... just became *"I tried running memtest before but I couldn't get it to complete. It froze right about the 30th loop without finding any problems"*.

We have a problem.

AMD processors are very fussy about RAM, and we may have a incompatible SODIMM. Testing further...

- remove the 2G SODIMM and rerun memtest
- remove the 4G SODIMM and reinsert the 2G SODIMM and rerun memtest

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123398/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-20-04-is-constantly-freezing).